# IntelliJ Grails app installed plugin not visible

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

Got a small question that ruins my day. I've got the Grails application that I want to import to IntelliJ. The problem is that IntelliJ can't find the springsecurity plugin, and doesn't see the @Secured annotation. The plugin *is* present in the "Tools->Grails plugins" window.

I'm using Idea 9.0 and grails 1.3.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try [IDEA X](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+X+EAP), a lot has happened in this field since 9.0. 
I'm using IDEA X build 98.311, and I'm able to see springsecurity plugin and the @Secured annotation

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, downloading it now.

Comment: Weeha! Works! Thanks, you saved the rest of my day!

Comment: IDEA 9.0 apparently hasn't integrated the plugin's dependencies, correctly.